# How to get current category id in view page of Magento?

Tags: magento-1.7

I have tried this code but while refreshing the page it gives me error.

$category_id = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();

Comment: Product View page or Category view page?

Comment: product view page

Comment: A product can be assigned in multiple categories at a time, so you can not get it by registry. You need to load product by id and then use **`$product->getCategoryIds();`** to get all category ids in which product has been assigned.

Comment: I cannot upvote for my own post

Comment: ok.. no issues :)